# Animate closing a browser window

Tags: jquery, css, animation, browser

Just curious, is there any way I can animate how a popup window closes? Right now I'm closing the popup window that I've created using plain Jquery but it would be great if I could get the window blur or fade away when I want it to close.

Comment: Did you try fadeOut();?

Comment: If by popup window you mean an actual browser window (and not a modal/overlay or something like that) - then the answer is no, of course.

Comment: @Cbroe Yeah I mean like an actual browser window. Why isn't this possible?

Comment: Because we’ve already seen in the past, how much people would abuse any control of the browsing environment past the boundaries of the viewport. Pop-unders that try to hide ads as long as possible from the user’s focus, on the other hand popups that fly over the screen to grab maximum attention …

Answer (score 0):

You can do Fade Out effect in jQuery.

This is the syntax

```
$(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)
$(selector).slideUp(speed,easing,callback)
```

and this is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/2a93p9gp/

added slideup effect, (also u can do many as you go)
https://jsfiddle.net/2a93p9gp/2/

Comment: Well while this would work for like a modal or overlay it wouldn't work for an actual browser window...